# Google Chart missing some month xAxis labels

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google column chart which is working as expected except that some of the month labels won't show. All of the months have data in them so I am puzzled as why some are not showing. As I am not an expert in mysql or php, I would love someone to point me in the right direction.

See image screenshot:
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex6zC.png)

```
   <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'farmrex');
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT
   MONTHNAME(expense_date) AS month,
   SUM(cost) AS total
FROM
   expenses
WHERE
   expense_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
GROUP BY
   YEAR(expense_date), MONTH(expense_date)");
//if($result){
//    echo "CONNECTED";
//}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
       function drawChart() {
           var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
               ['Date', 'Expense Amount'],

               <?php

                   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0){

                       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                           echo "['".$row['month']."', ".$row['total']."],";
                       }
                   }
               ?>

           ]);
           var options = {
               chart: {                    
                   title: 'Monthly Expenses',
                   subtitle: 'Last 12 months of expenses',
                   width: 5000,
                   height: 500
               },
               vAxis: {
         title: 'Expense Amount',
         format: '#,##0.00',
         format: 'currency'
       }
           };

           var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart'));

           chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
       }
   </script>

</head>
<body>

<section>
<div id="columnchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe try reducing the font size or making the chart wider. moving the legend to the top or bottom would most likely resolve the issue, but since you are using a _material_ chart, [this is not an option](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143).

Answer (score 0):

All good! I managed to fix the issue by using abbreviated month names.

Changed:

```
MONTHNAME(expense_date) AS month,
```

to:

```
DATE_FORMAT(expense_date, '%b') AS month,
```